# React DevTool's highlighting of Components and how it works

Tags: reactjs

TLDR; Why is the React DevTool's highlighting option marking child components as "updating" when it's parent is **already** marked as "updating"?

I have a small React App where I fetch data from a server and set it as `state`. The view updates as expected and everything is working fine.

When I then tried to trace which components are updated I found myself confused, since not only was the parent marked as "updating" in the React DevTools, but also the children. I expected only the parent to be marked as "updating" since marking the parent **and** the children seemed redundant (a re-rendering parent implies that all children are re-rendering as well as far as I know).

Never the less I realised that I had some improvements to do in the child components anyway, so I sat down and cleaned up my code performance wise.

When I was done doing that, I was faced with the  next surprise. When I was checking the DevTools for "updating" components again, I saw that now my children are not marked as "updating" any more. The parent however still was, which I expected anyway.

My question now is: ***Have I achieved a performance improvement?*** The children are not marked as "updating" any more, but the Parent still is, which means that the children must be updating anyway, right?

Clarification would be appreciated! :)

Comment: children of course was rerendered but result in virtual tree was the same as earlier, not different to existing (old) real DOM, then **update** for this nodes not needed

Comment: But the children are re-rendered. So there was no performance improvement? @xadm

Comment: Updating DOM is the most costly process (virtual render is cheap). Updating (real DOM) with the same content would cost time the same as updating with updated content - avoiding unnecessary updates gives performance improvement. Avoiding render would give additional improvement, of course.

Comment: Children re-rendering is usually the result of of functional components (I.E doesn't extend Component or PureComponent). You can usually get some optimization by using PureComponents in place of functional ones.